# How to get current message Id in Gmail using AppScript?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, google-workspace-add-ons

So, I was looking around the internet for a code to get the current message Id or just current message but I cannot seem to find it. What I actually want is, when I click on a mail and open it, the add-on I am working on should be able to get the message or the message id so that I can get hold of some information from that mail. How do I do it? I tried few things but cannot seem to get it working. Any idea? any suggestion is greatly appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I  did solve it and all thanks to @TheMaster for his help. So, What I did was I edited the manifest file and then added the code in my code.gs file.
This is what I added in my Manifest file,

```
"addOns": {
    "common": {
      "name": "Attatchment Downloader",
      "logoUrl": "URL FOR LOGO"
    },
    "gmail": {
      "contextualTriggers": [
        {
          "unconditional": {},
          "onTriggerFunction": "onGmailMessageOpen"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

You can enable the manifest file to be displayed along with other files by going to project settings and enabling it there.

and then the `onGMailMessageOpen` function inside the code.gs file.
So when the user opens any message, this function is automatically called and an `eventobject` is passed to it. So using this event object we can access the EMail/Message that is currently open, but first you will need to get the access token like the code below and get hold of the current message and its Id.

```
function onGmailMessageOpen(eventObject){
  // Activate temporary Gmail scopes, in this case to allow
  // message metadata to be read.
  var accessToken = eventObject.gmail.accessToken;
  GmailApp.setCurrentMessageAccessToken(accessToken);

  var messageId = eventObject.gmail.messageId;
}
```

you can also get all of these from the official documentation, through this link,

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail ,

you might have to find what your looking for as there is lot to take in.

Answer (score 1):

If you use [google-workspace-add-ons](/questions/tagged/google-workspace-add-ons), you can use [Contextual triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/gmail/extending-message-ui) to automatically run a function, when opening a message (and clicking your addon icon or of addon homepage is already open). The function that is set to trigger will receive a [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/concepts/event-objects#gmail-event-object), which will contain the message id.

```
const functionThatIsSetToRunWhenUserOpensAGmail = (eventObject) => {
  const messageId = eventObject.gmail.messageId;
}
```

Comment: used the Triggers and the code you provided, I get an error saying gmail is undefined. When I check the `eventObject`, I get it as undefined. Here is my manifest file that I edited,
 `"addOns": {
    "common": {
      "name": "gmail",
      "logoUrl": ""
    },
    "gmail": {
      "contextualTriggers": [
        {
          "unconditional": {},
          "onTriggerFunction": "onGmailMessageOpen"
        }
      ]
    }
  }`
Any Idea what could I be doing wrong? I have already created a trigger for onGmailOpen too.

Comment: @Dilip  1. What is undefined? Quote the exact text of the error. 2. How are you calling this function?

Comment: I have created a trigger as you suggested and this function gets called when I open a Mail Message, and it calls this function,
'const onGmailMessageOpen = (eventObject) => {
  const messageId = eventObject.gmail.messageId;
  console.log(messageId);
}'
So, here, I get, `Error 
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'gmail')`

I believe the eventObject is Null or something. Does this makes sense?

Comment: @Dilip Are you manually calling the function? For there to be a event object, it should automatically be triggered.

Comment: I went into the triggers section and created a trigger called OnGmailMessageOpen and this trigger calls the function when a user opens email message,

function OnGmailMessageOpen(){
}.... Thats how I have understood, not sure if it is totally correct or not. Any Suggestions?

Comment: @Dilip you don't have to(shouldn't) create a trigger in the triggers section. You just update the manifest appsscript.json  and it should automatically call this function.

Comment: I just checked it, OnGmailMessageOpen function is not automatically being called no matter what I do, I even removed the trigger from the trigger section and it still didn't get executed. I guess there's something wrong with my manifest.json file. 

Could you let me know how do I update my manifest file properly to execute this function automatically upon opening a gmail message? would be a great help. Thank You. I was going to paste my manifest here but the character limi!!!!!

I have actually done this too,

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/gmail/extending-message-ui

Comment: @Dilip It'll only be automatically called, if the homepage card is already open or if the user clicks your addon icon, when that specific message is open.

Comment: I got it working, what I basically did was remove the triggers from trigger section and just add the code from the official documentation along with the tips you provided. Thanks alot!!!